# import DLL with extern "C++"

Tags: c++, dll

When I write DLLs I usually use code like that

```
extern "C"
{
//some declarations
}
```

but how exactly can I dynamically load a function from DLL which has been written this way

```
extern "C++"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) int Foo(int x)
    {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

?

Of course I can manually decorate name by writing code like that

```
int (*Foo)(int);
Foo = (int(*)(int)) GetProcAddress(hModule, "?Foo@@YAHH@Z");
```

and it will work, but it should be some normal way to do it.

Comment: Of course you can use the decorated name.  It is *safer*, you'll get an early diagnostic of a guaranteed runtime problem when the exported function's signature is changed.  Otherwise, you *must* either use `extern "C"` or a .def file to rename the export.

Comment: Decorated names are usually not used with `GetProcAddress`, only with an import library, where the compiler will perform the mangling automatically.  If you want to make dynamic loading easy, I recommend disabling mangling for those names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to export a C++ function then then name will be mangled, as you've discovered.

You can use a [module definition file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/d91k01sh.aspx) to export the mangled function with a particular ordinal. Once you've done this you can use `GetProcAddress` to import via this ordinal:

```
Foo = (int(*)(int)) GetProcAddress(hModule, MAKEINTRESOURCE(FOO_ORDINAL));
```